# call a function from inside a function php oop

Tags: php, oop, class, function, call

I wonder if this is possible, although I'm quite convince maybe there is a better approach for this. I have this script structure:

```
class Mother {
    public function __construct() {
        // script here
    }

    public function writer() {
        if() {
            // if true
        } else {
            // call function hello
        }
    }

    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello there.";
    }
}
```

How can I call hello() from writer()? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so

```
public function writer() {
    $this->hello();
}
```

`$this` is a reserved variable for classes, any class that is instantiated (called via `new myClass`) has access to `$this`, however if you're using a static class, you would need to define that function as static and use the `static::myFunction` approach, for example:

```
class exampleClass {
    public static function exampleFunc() {
        static::hello();
    }
    public static function hello() {
        echo "Hello!";
    }
}
exampleClass::exampleFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick feedback, may I ask is this the best approach?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the only approach, unless you're using the class statically, in that case refer to the example in my updated post, otherwise `$this` is the best way to access functions inside the same class.

Comment: Very enlightening in just a matter of minutes, huge thanks Nexerus.

Answer (score 0):

```
// call function hello
$this->hello();
```

Also, your other functions are syntactically wrong. Note the parenthesis.

```
public function writer() {
public function hello() {
```

Answer (score 0):

on my PHP 5.3.4 installation

```
public function hello() { }
```

seems to to available from another instance method in two ways

```
$this->hello()
self::hello()
```

Obviously,

```
$this
```

the reference to the instance will not be available when calling a public method as a class method